# Scala Map from Test File

Tags: scala, mapping, txt

Looking to create a scala map from a test file. A sample of the text file (a few lines of it) can be seen below:

```
Alabama (9),Democratic:849624,Republican:1441170,Libertarian:25176,Others:7312
Alaska (3),Democratic:153778,Republican:189951,Libertarian:8897,Others:6904
Arizona (11),Democratic:1672143,Republican:1661686,Libertarian:51465,Green:1557,Others:475
```

I have been given the map buffer as follows:

```
var mapBuffer: Map[String, List[(String, Int)]] = Map()
```

Note the party values are separated by a colon.

I am trying to read the file contents and store the data in a map structure where each line of the file is used to construct a map entry with the date as the key, and a list of tuples as the value. The type of the structure should be Map[String, List[(String,Int)]].

Essentially just trying to create a map of each line from the file but I can't quite get it right. I tried the below but with not luck - I think that 'val lines' should be an array rather than an iterator.

```
val stream : InputStream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("")
      val lines: Iterator[String] = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(stream).getLines
      var map: Map[String, List[(String, Int)]] = lines
        .map(_.split(","))
        .map(line => (line(0).toString, line(1).toList))
        .toMap
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to do the job. (Scala 2.13.x)

```
val stateVotes =
  util.Using(io.Source.fromFile("votes.txt")){
    val PartyVotes = "([^:]+):(\\d+)".r
    _.getLines()
     .map(_.split(",").toList)
     .toList
     .groupMapReduce(_.head)(_.tail.collect{
          case PartyVotes(p,v) => (p,v.toInt)})(_ ++ _)
  } //file is auto-closed

//stateVotes: Try[Map[String,List[(String, Int)]]] = Success(
// Map(Alabama (9) -> List((Democratic,849624), (Republican,1441170), (Libertarian,25176), (Others,7312))
//   , Arizona (11) -> List((Democratic,1672143), (Republican,1661686), (Libertarian,51465), (Green,1557), (Others,475))
//   , Alaska (3) -> List((Democratic,153778), (Republican,189951), (Libertarian,8897), (Others,6904))))
```

In this case the number following the state name is preserved. That can be changed.

Comment: Do you have any advice on how to make each state a singleton object from the map? Essentially trying to make val arizona = (Democratic,849624).... so that it can be called by an application to display this data - any help would be appreciated! @jwvh

Comment: Your terminology is a bit confused. You say you want "_a singleton object_," which would mean `object Arizona {...}`, but then you give an example of `val arizona = ...`, which would be a variable. Then you say "_it can be called by an application_," which indicates a function. My advice is to post a new question with a **clear** description of what you're trying to achieve and an example of how you'd like the client code (the caller) to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 2):

No, iterator is fine (better than list actually),
you just need to split the values too to create those tuples.

```
    lines
      .map(_.split(","))
      .map { case l => 
         l.head -> l.tail.toList.map(_.split(":"))
                     .collect { case Seq(a,b) => a -> b.toInt }
      }
      .toMap
```

An alternative that looks a little bit more aesthetic to my eye is converting to map early, and then using `mapValues` (I personally much
prefer short lambdas). The downside is `mapValues` is lazy, so you end up
having to do `.toMap` twice to force it in the end:

```
   lines
     .map(_.split(","))
     .map { case l => l.head -> l.tail.toList }
     .toMap
     .mapValues(_.split(":"))
     .mapValues(_.collect { case Seq(a,b) => a -> b.toInt })
     .toMap
```